# Managing multiple routes in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I know Spring Cloud Gateway has multiple ways to configure routes:

- using a Java-based DSL `(eg: using RouteLocatorBuilder)` and/or
- property based configuration.

The offical Spring Cloud Gateway [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#configuring-route-predicate-factories-and-gateway-filter-factories) use properties to manage routes.

My questions are:

- It is simple to configure routes for 2-3 microservices in a single file, but how do enterprise applications with so many microservices manage routes efficiently?
- What is the recommend way to configure routes?
- If using Java DSL, is it a good practice to use multiple `Beans` with the same return type. something like:

```java
    @Bean
    RouteLocator bookRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                      .route("book_route", r -> r.method(HttpMethod.GET)
                      .and().path("/api/book/**")
                      .uri("lb://book-service"))
                      .build();
    }

    @Bean
    RouteLocator chapterRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                      .route("chapter_route", r -> r.method(HttpMethod.GET)
                      .and().path("/api/chapter/**")
                      .uri("lb://chapter-service"))
                      .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a decently old post but this is something I recently ran into and wanted to share a solution.

Exposing multiple beans will not work - those two RouteLocator instances will collide with each other causing an error or you can allow spring to override the other bean - either way, its not going to work for you.

Instead, expose a Router that references other classes that expose functions that create your routes. Here is an example in Kotlin

Routes.kt

```java
@Configuration
class Routes(
   private val purchaseRoute: PurchaseRoute
) {

    @Bean
    fun router(routeLocatorBuilder: RouteLocatorBuilder): RouteLocator {
        return routeLocatorBuilder.routes()
            .route("purchase", purchaseRoute.route())
            .build()
    }

}
```

Router.kt interface all sub-routes will implement

```java
interface Router {
    fun route(): Function<PredicateSpec, Buildable<Route>>
}
```

PurchaseRoute.kt

```java
@Configuration
class PurchaseRoute() : Router {
    override fun route(): Function<PredicateSpec, Buildable<Route>> =
        Function {
            it.path("/api/purchase/**")
            it.filters {
                stripPrefix(1)
                dedupeResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "RETAIN_FIRST")
            }
            it.uri(routeConfigProperties.uri)
        }
}
```

Then just create as many route classes as you like. The separation into multiple files dramatically cleaned up a gateway service I maintain.