separate individual routes in spring cloud gateway
I am using Spring Cloud Gateway(Spring Boot 2.7.X) to route/POST request to different external endpoints for configured customers. The routes are configured in application yml.
With more and more customers getting added, defining all 'routes' (plus filters, headers etc) is causing the application yml file to grow and hard to maintain/read (also prone to mix ups).
Tried few approaches like Spring profile include / Spring config import, but so far unable to successfully configure (with possible conflict in routes).
Appreciate any suggestions/thoughts?

not really, since this is way too abstract, what do you want us to suggest? I would say you should rethink your design, each customer gets a different URL? could you just navigate them to one (or few) service(s) which then processes customers based on some parameter? in any case with such little info can't really advise anything

thanks @JAsgarov. Each customer has their own url.  So you are suggesting to NOT use Spring Cloud Gateway and using some kind of custom routing solution to call specific services ? How will it still resolve avoiding cluttering of yaml file where each customer has their own endpoints / authentication mechanism etc that are defined in yaml file (with Spring Cloud gateway able to reuse same filters etc as well)

I didn't say don't use cloud gateway, I asked if you could generalize customers into groups and send all members of some group to a single service. So instead of creating 300 routes, you could define 3 routes for 3 somewhat similar groups of consumers. But again this is way too abstract, I am giving advice on something you provided no info for, so I have no idea what you need

updated my comments, as mistakenly posted earlier, please review

i found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69592731/managing-multiple-routes-in-spring-cloud-gateway but exploring how can this be done where routes are configured in property files
